How to automate Visual studio import database project feature?
I am looking for a way to automatize multiple time this Visual Studio feature
I have a SQL project with many database and I want to manage it with Git to insure the code management.
To do it I planned to use SQL  project from visual Studio to export SQL database architecture to a file project.
Today, I didn't plan to change my team members way of work so I won't ask them to develop into Visual Studio project they will continue to manage the DB directly. The aim of the project is to follow the current Database state into the Git repo.
My problem is that as I have many DB, I have to reproduce for each DB the follwing command
It took a long time and there is a risk of error during the process, so I would to be able to do it with a script. Do you know how I could call this feature from a command line ?

In my opinion, we have is an XY Problem here. "I didn't plan to change my team members way of work so I won't ask them to develop into Visual Studio project they will continue to manage the DB directly." Then you need a different solution; one that allows for source control to be managed at the database level, not the project level. We use SQL Source Control at the office, for example (I am not affiliated in any way with Redgate). If you don't want to do that, then you need to change the way your developers develop.
